# How can I show images for pagination when using the jQuery DataTables plugin?

Tags: jquery-plugins, datatables

I'd like to show images instead of the "next" "last" text that is displayed now.  I tried to just override the text currently being displayed and it didn't seem to change anything.  The "next" "last" text is still displayed, let alone I still have no idea how to change it to images.

```
$('#myTable').dataTable({
 "aaSorting": [[ 1, "asc" ]],
 "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "oPaginate": 
    {
        "sNext": 'n',
        "sLast": 'l',
        "sFirst": 'f',
        "sPrevious": 'p'
    }
});
```

Anyone know how to do this?  I would think it would be on the lines of:

```
    "oPaginate": 
    {
        "sNext": '<img src="myimage.jpg" />',
...
    }
```

Comment: Did you try the solution you suggested (using the img tag as sNext)?

Comment: i did and nothing changed.  I'm guessing I have a syntax error although I'm not getting errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One year late, but this looks like it's still an unanswered question.

To be able to change the default values of next/last buttons you need to pass the `oPaginate` object as part of the `oLanguage` object, like so:

```
$('#myTable').dataTable({
 "aaSorting": [[ 1, "asc" ]],
 "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
 "oLanguage": {
    "oPaginate": {
        "sNext": 'n',
        "sLast": 'l',
        "sFirst": 'f',
        "sPrevious": 'p'
     }
  }
});
```

[Source](http://datatables.net/usage/i18n)

Answer (score 3):

this was a long time ago, but the answer he provided should work...
i have  this, and it works:

```
oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
        "ordering": false,
        //"sDom":"flrtip"
        "sDom":'r<"contactsTable"t><p>',
        "oLanguage": {
            "oPaginate": {
              "sNext": '<i class="entypo-right-circled" ></i>',
              "sPrevious": '<i class="entypo-left-circled" class="Dia_pagination_ico" ></i>'
            }
          }
    });
```

the css class puts the image, but im guessing the example given should work

Answer (score 1):

You can change them using CSS..

Take a look at my example:

http://www(@)fisheragservice(@)com/tm/users(@)html

The page contains email addresses and don't want the spam bots to index them, so please replace the (@)'s with .'s

You can view the source to see how it was done..  Hope this helps..

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking that this would work as well, but was thinking it would be easier to just change the text that was being put out.

Comment: did you remove the page? it is now blank.

Comment: Shoot I guess I should have copied some of the source to the answer because I remember looking but now need to implement the answer now that it is blank.